# EventPluginUtils.getLowestCommonAncestor(responderInst, targetInst) error react-native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I recently updated my react-native app to use the latest version (ie. 0.44). The app starts up fine in the simulator and mobile device however whenever a component is pressed like a button or some other widget, the red error screen appears with the following error:

[image: screenshot of the error when app running on a mobile device]

Also when running the app on the ios or android simulator, the error has a slightly different flavor:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hi that function was moved to another class, probably you are using a component not updated which search for the function in his old location. you can either downgrade you RN or see if the component have been updated

[position before](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/b1da7a5f5d4152387feab26bdadd69188efd55f2#diff-6e391ee1e1fa8b25c6d240e16bca2720L242)

[position after](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/b1da7a5f5d4152387feab26bdadd69188efd55f2#diff-9f1e52403485ae888d9d50646b96ea00R335)

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue after upgrading to react-native0.44. Then I figured out, it is due to react-native-router-flux Version: 3.38.1

Changed dependencies in package.json under react-native-router-flux from following:

```
"lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
"react": "^15.4.2",
"react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.4.2",
"react-dom": "^15.4.2",
"react-native": "^0.41.2",
"react-native-experimental-navigation": "0.26.x",
"react-native-tabs": "^1.0.9",
"react-static-container": "1.0.1"
```

To following:

```
"lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
"react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.4.2",
"react-dom": "^15.4.2",
"react-native": "^0.44.0",
"react-native-experimental-navigation": "0.26.x",
"react-native-tabs": "^1.0.9",
"react-static-container": "1.0.1"
```

Then run npm install in ./node_modules/react-native-router-flux folder.